# Sum of Betti numbers of a degree $d$ hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the zero set of a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$. Assume that $X$ is smooth. Is there a way to find the sum of the Betti numbers of $X$ (i.e. the ranks of the (singular) homology groups over a field $k$)? I am glad about any kind of results and in particular I am interested in the case when $k=\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the field with two elements. If not, can we at least bound it from above?

Comment: The answer is the same regardless of the coefficient rings because all of the homology groups are free. You can also see the computation in a bit more detail at https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/hypersurfaces-4-manifolds-and-characteristic-classes/.

Comment: wait, why does the freeness of the homology groups imply that the result doesn't depend on the coefficient ring? I mean tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not exact right? Also, does the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem hold for $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: It means that all of the Tor and Ext terms in the universal coefficient theorems for both homology and cohomology vanish. You only need to invoke the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem over $\mathbb{Z}$, and after that it's just a matter of using the universal coefficient theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem, the inclusion $i : X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{CP}^n$ induces a map $i^* : H^q(\mathbb{CP}^n, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^q(X, \mathbb{Z})$ which is an isomorphism for $q \leq n - 2$ and is injective for $q = n - 1$. Recall that

$$b_q(\mathbb{CP}^n) = \operatorname{rank} H^q(\mathbb{CP}^n, \mathbb{Z}) = \begin{cases}
1 & q\ \text{even}, 0 \leq q \leq 2n,\\
&\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Note that $X$ has complex dimension $n - 1$ and therefore real dimension $2n - 2$. By Poincaré duality $b_q(X) = b_{2n - 2 - q}(X)$, so the only Betti number of $X$ that we haven't established is $b_{n-1}(X)$.

Combining these results, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{q=0}^{2n-2}b_q(X) &= \sum_{q=0}^{n-2}b_q(X) + b_{n-1}(X) + \sum_{q=n}^{2n-2}b_q(X)\\ 
&= 2\sum_{q=0}^{n-2}b_q(X) + b_{n-1}(X)\\ 
&= 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + b_{n-1}(X).
\end{align*}

However, we know that $b_{n - 1}(X) \geq b_{n-1}(\mathbb{CP}^n)$ by the injectivity of $i^*$. Therefore

$$\sum_{q=0}^{2n-2}b_q(X) = b_{n-1}(X) + 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor  \geq b_{n-1}(\mathbb{CP}^n) + 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor = n.$$

---

Note, you can actually determine $b_{n-1}(X)$ (and hence the sum) exactly, but the expression is a little complicated. I won't put in all the details right now, but here's how it goes.

First, let $B(X)$ denote the sum of Betti numbers of $X$. Using the results above, one can show that $B(X) = \chi(X) + (1 - (-1)^{n-1})b_{n-1}(X)$; in particular, if $n$ is odd, we see that $B(X) = \chi(X)$. Combining with the expression for $B(X)$ above, we see that $b_{n-1}(X) = (-1)^{n-1}(\chi(X) - 2\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)$.

Using Chern classes, one can show that the Euler characteristic of $X$ is given by

$$\chi(X) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^jd^{j+1}\binom{n+1}{j+2}.$$

Therefore, assuming I haven't made any mistakes, we have

$$B(X) = 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + (-1)^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^jd^{j+1}\binom{n+1}{j+2} - 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right),$$

which can be rewritten as

$$B(X) = (-1)^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^jd^{j+1}\binom{n+1}{j+2} + 2(1 - (-1)^{n-1})\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor.$$

Splitting into cases, we have

$$B(X) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^jd^{j+1}\binom{n+1}{j+2} & n\ \text{odd},\\
&\\
-\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^jd^{j+1}\binom{n+1}{j+2} + 2n & n\ \text{even}.
\end{cases}$$

which is the same as

$$B(X) = \begin{cases}
\chi(X) & n\ \text{odd},\\
&\\
-\chi(X) + 2n & n\ \text{even}.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I wish I had seen your answer here before I spent all that time typing mine! :)

Comment: @Relapsarian: I think your answer is good too. It explains the stuff about Chern classes that I used but didn't write about.

Comment: And yours writes out the formulas that I was too lazy to typset. I am not registered so I can't vote, but a figurative +1 from me.

Answer (score 7):

(Let me answer the case of coefficients in $\mathbf Z$ (or $\mathbf Q$ or $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$.) I think it should only take a bit of universal coefficient wizardry to deduce the answer in general, but it is too late here for that.)

1. First, by the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem and Poincaré duality, we have an isomorphism 
   $$ H_i(\mathbf P^n, \mathbf Z) \cong H_i(X,\mathbf Z)$$ 
   for all $i$ except $i=\operatorname{dim } X$. So  there is only one Betti number left to find.
2. Since we know all but one Betti number, and we know which degree the missing one is in, finding that last one is equivalent to finding the Euler characteristic. But now the Euler characteristic is the degree of the top Chern class $c_{n-1}(X)$. Finally, to calculate that, we use the exact sequence of bundles
   $$ 0 \rightarrow T_X \rightarrow (T_{\mathbf P^n})_{|X} \rightarrow N_X \rightarrow 0 $$
   (where $N_X$ is the normal bundle) and the Whitney sum formula, which gives

$$ c(T_{\mathbf P^n})_{|X}  = c(T_X)\, c(N_X) .$$

The Euler sequence gives $c(T_{\mathbf P^n})=(1+H)^{n+1}$, and it is a basic fact about hypersurfaces that $c(N_X)=(1+dH)_{|X}$. Putting all this together, you can calculate the required class $c_{n-1}(T_X)$ and get your answer.

*Exercise:* Apply the above in the case where $X$ is a smooth quartic surface in $\mathbf P^3$ and show that $b_2(X)=22$.